How to copy all sheets in an Excel workbook using a formula?
All I want to do is create copies of every sheet in my excel. The caveat is that they should be copied using a formula. For example if there is one sheet in the workbook named "sheet1" then it should create a sheet named "sheet1_c" with the following formula in all cells where there is data in sheet1: =IF('sheet1'!A1="", "", 'sheet1'!A1). It should do this for every sheet in the excel.
I have written VBA that works for one sheet that is currently active:
Sub CopySheet()

    OptimizeCode
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim newSheet As Worksheet
    Dim wsName As String
    Dim newSheetName As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim formulaText As String
    Dim cellAddress As String

    ' Set the current worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    ' Get the current sheet name
    wsName = ws.Name

    ' Create the new sheet name
    newSheetName = wsName & "_c"

    ' Check if a sheet with the new name already exists
    On Error Resume Next
    Set newSheet = Worksheets(newSheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' If the sheet exists, delete it
    If Not newSheet Is Nothing Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        newSheet.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If

    ' Add a new worksheet with the new name
    Set newSheet = Worksheets.Add(After:=ws)
    newSheet.Name = newSheetName

    ' Copy the formulas from the original sheet to the new sheet
    For Each cell In ws.UsedRange
        ' Construct the formula using relative references
        cellAddress = cell.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
        formulaText = "=IF(" & wsName & "!" & cellAddress & "="" "",""""," & wsName & "!" & cellAddress & ")"
        newSheet.Range(cell.Address).Formula = formulaText
    Next cell

    ' Optionally, you can select the new sheet after copying
    newSheet.Select

    DefaultSettings
    
End Sub

I tried to expand it to all worksheets using this code:
Sub CopyAllSheets()
    OptimizeCode
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim newSheet As Worksheet
    Dim wsName As String
    Dim newSheetName As String
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim cellAddress As String
    Dim formulaText As String
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim sheetExists As Boolean

    ' Loop through all worksheets in the workbook
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    
        ' Get the current sheet name
        wsName = ws.Name
    
        ' Create the new sheet name
        newSheetName = wsName & "_c"
    
        ' Check if a sheet with the new name already exists
        On Error Resume Next
        Set newSheet = Worksheets(newSheetName)
        On Error GoTo 0
    
        ' If the sheet exists, delete it
        If Not newSheet Is Nothing Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            newSheet.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    
        ' Add a new worksheet with the new name
        Set newSheet = Worksheets.Add(After:=ws)
        newSheet.Name = newSheetName
    
        ' Copy the formulas from the original sheet to the new sheet
        For Each cell In ws.UsedRange
            ' Construct the formula using relative references
            cellAddress = cell.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
            formulaText = "=IF(" & wsName & "!" & cellAddress & "="" "",""""," & wsName & "!" & cellAddress & ")"
            newSheet.Range(cell.Address).Formula = formulaText
        Next cell
        
    Next ws

    DefaultSettings
    
End Sub

When I try to run this code, it opens the file explorer asking for an input file to update values in the new sheet. Does anyone have any insight as to why this is happening and how I can convert my code that works on one sheet to work on all sheets?

do your sheet names have spaces in them or special characters?

no they are just the default sheet names so sheet1, sheet2, etc.

This works for me:
Sub CopyAllSheets()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, col As Collection, wb As Workbook
    Dim newSheet As Worksheet
    Dim newSheetName As String
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim cellAddress As String, formulaText As String
    
    Set col = New Collection
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    ' First collect all non-"_c" worksheets in the workbook
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If Not ws.Name Like "*_c" Then col.Add ws
    Next ws
    
    'process the collected sheets
    For Each ws In col
        newSheetName = ws.Name & "_c"
        DeleteSheetIfExists wb, newSheetName
        Set newSheet = Worksheets.Add(After:=ws)
        newSheet.Name = newSheetName
        For Each cell In ws.UsedRange.Cells
            cellAddress = cell.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
            'quote all sheet names in case of spaces
            formulaText = "=IF('" & ws.Name & "'!" & cellAddress & _
                          "="""","""",'" & ws.Name & "'!" & cellAddress & ")"
            newSheet.Range(cell.Address).Formula = formulaText
        Next cell
    Next ws

End Sub

'remove worksheet `wsName` from workbook `wb` if it exists
Sub DeleteSheetIfExists(wb As Workbook, wsName As String)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    wb.Worksheets(wsName).Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

You're adding/removing sheets while looping over ThisWorkbook.Worksheets, so it's best to first collect the specific sheets you're interested in, and then process that collection.
If source sheet names may contain spaces it's best to quote the names in the formula.
Your formula is checking for a single space, not for empty cells.  Fixed above.

The code seems to be running as intended, except for the fact that it is collecting a bunch of sheet names that I do not have in my workbook. When I step through the code, I see it adds "sheet1", "sheet2", "sheet11", etc. to the collection, but it does not add the one sheet I actually had in the workbook named "a". It then tries to open the file explorer because it is using a formula that links to a sheet that does not exist in the workbook. Any idea what could be causing this?

Is the code in the same workbook as the worksheets? Or in a different workbook?   Maybe you want Set wb = ActiveWorkbook ?  (or some other specific workbook)

Yes that was the problem. I have my macros in my personal workbook. Updating that line in the code fixed the issue. Thanks so much for your help.

Please flag as "Accepted" if this answered your question, to help out anyone coming along later with a similar problem.

Create Copies of All Worksheets
Sub CopyAllSheets()
    
    Const SUFFIX As String = "_c" ' make sure a 'keeper' doesn't end with it
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    DeleteWorksheetsMatchingPattern wb, "*" & SUFFIX ' ends with
    CreateWorksheetCopiesWithSuffix wb, SUFFIX
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Copies of all worksheets created.", vbInformation
    
End Sub

Sub DeleteWorksheetsMatchingPattern( _
        ByVal wb As Workbook, _
        ByVal SheetNamePattern As String)

    Dim SheetPattern As String: SheetPattern = LCase(SheetNamePattern)
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Long
    
    For i = wb.Worksheets.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets(i)
        If LCase(ws.Name) Like SheetPattern Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                ws.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    Next i

End Sub

Sub CreateWorksheetCopiesWithSuffix( _
        ByVal wb As Workbook, _
        ByVal SuffixString As String)
    
    Const GEN_SHEET As String = "SSSS"
    Const GEN_CELL As String = "CCCC"
    
    Dim GEN_FORMULA As String: GEN_FORMULA = "=IF('" _
        & GEN_SHEET & "'!" & GEN_CELL & "="""","""",'" _
        & GEN_SHEET & "'!" & GEN_CELL & ")"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rg As Range, i As Long
    Dim UsedRangeAddress As String, Formula As String
    
    For i = wb.Worksheets.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets(i)
        Set rg = ws.UsedRange
        
        UsedRangeAddress = rg.Address(0, 0)
        Formula = Replace(GEN_FORMULA, GEN_CELL, rg.Cells(1).Address(0, 0))
        Formula = Replace(Formula, GEN_SHEET, ws.Name)
        
        With wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=ws).Range(UsedRangeAddress)
            .Parent.Name = ws.Name & SuffixString
            'rg.Copy
            '.PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths ' column widths
            'rg.Copy Destination:=.Cells ' formatting (and values)
            .Formula = Formula
        End With
    Next i

End Sub

